# Jersey Library errors (NoSuchMethod then IncompatibleClassChangeError)

Tags: maven, jersey, weblogic, java

We just upgraded from Weblogic 10 to Weblogic 12 and started to get this error

```
<Error> <com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse> <hostname> <nodename> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '21' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <ws_user> <> <> <140123234234> <BEA-000000> <The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jersey.client.apache.ApacheHttpClientHandler.getRequestEntityWriter(Lcom/sun/jersey/api/client/ClientRequest;)Lcom/sun/jersey/api/client/TerminatingClientHandler$RequestEntityWriter
```

After little bit digging, I realized that Jersey library (`com.sun.jersey.contribs`) needs to be upgraded to `1.18.1` version from `1.2`. I did that change and then started to get following error

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider and com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$Wadl disagree on InnerClasses attribute
```

a little digging in it i learned that my JSR311-api (`javax.ws.rs`) has to be `1.1.1` and it is already that. Now i am lost what else shall i change to have these errors fixed

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when updating the Jersey library. In the end it turned out that the old jar was still in the /lib folder. Make sure that you have completely removed the previous version.

Hope that helps.